# Difference between vector and pseudovector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

There is a definition of a pseudovector on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector).
On the top right there is this image with explanation:
[image]

> A loop of wire (black), carrying a current I, creates a magnetic field
> B (blue). If the position and current of the wire are reflected across
> the plane indicated by the dashed line, the magnetic field it
> generates would not be reflected: Instead, it would be reflected and
> reversed. The position of the wire and its current are "true" vectors,
> but the magnetic field B is a pseudovector.

OK I understand the issue with mirror reflection but then I can say the opposite:

We have a loop of wire in a magnetic field `B` which creates current `I` in the wire.  If the position and magnetic field are reflected across the plane indicated by the dashed line, the current it generates would not be reflected: Instead, it would be reflected and reversed. The position of the wire and its magnetic field are "true" vectors, but the current `I` is a pseudovector.

Here it is how it would look:

[image]

So I came to an opposite conclusion - `B` is true vector and `I` is pseudovector. Where is my logic wrong?

Comment: This is more of a physics question than math. Essentially, you mirror every instance of position in your formalism, specifically the position of all particles. This also leads to mirrored velocities, if we don't also mirror time (and we don't do that). And current depends on the velocity of charged particles. So mirroring position leads to mirrored current - which does not lead to mirrored magnetic fields. So it boils down to the fact that noone told you to mirror currents or field lines, so you don't arbitrarily mirror them, unless they depend on something which you *are* told to mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec I$ represents true physical motion, so it must be reflected when you reflect the coordinates.  We don't know about $\vec B$ until we chase through the situation.